# How can I use GetElementByID to output the same input twice?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a signature block generator for my company, and I need to be able to output the name of individuals twice.  Once in the outgoing email, and another in the reply.  I've tried using GetElementByID, and that works fine for one, but not two.  I've tried GetElementsByName, but failed.  https://codepen.io/jggrs/pen/paZyrN

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function getOption(){
            var firstlast = document.getElementById("firstlast").value;
            display_firstlast.innerHTML= firstlast;
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
First and Last Name: <input type="text" id = "firstlast">&nbsp;
<input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Make My Signature">
</form>


<!--NAME AND TITLE-->
<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast"></span></p>

<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't give more than one element the same id, they have to be unique.

Comment: Also, your id is "display_firstlast", but you're only getting the element with the id "firstlast". And then you try to operate on the nonexistent variable "display_firstlast".

Answer (score 1):

Always use class for stuff like that

1- get all elements by class name

2- convert it to a array so you can loop in it ([].slice.call() convert a HTMLCollection to a array)

3- change the innerHTML of each

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function getOption(){
        var firstlast = document.getElementById("firstlast").value;
        var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_firstlast'));

      list.forEach(function(item){

      item.innerHTML= firstlast
      });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
First and Last Name: <input type="text" id = "firstlast">&nbsp;
<input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Make My Signature">
</form>


<!--NAME AND TITLE-->
<p>My name is <span class="display_firstlast"></span></p>

<p>My name is <span class="display_firstlast"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is going here is that an id in javascript must be unique to one and only one element, However, this can be done by assigning a class to the both p tags or by simply:

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function getOption(){
            var firstlast = document.getElementById("firstlast").value;
  document.geElementById('display_firstlast').innerHTML= firstlast;
document.geElementById('display_firstlast2').innerHTML = firstlast;

        }

</script>
<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast"></span></p>

<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast2"></span></p>
```

Comment: That code still won't work, because it's looking for the wrong id, and using wrong variable names.

Comment: There Herohtar, now it will work,,,, the idea was explaining what is wrong with his code not writing code for him ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  var name = document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value;
  var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#display_firstlast'));
  
  for ( var e of items ) {
    e.innerHTML = name;  
  }
});
```

```html
<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast"></span></p>

<p>My name is <span id = "display_firstlast"></span></p>

<div><input type="text" value="A Name" /> <button>Set Name</button></div>
```

As many people have said you SHOULD be using classes for that; however, you can also do this if you really need it as an id =>

```
document.querySelectorAll('#display_firstlast')
```

that should get both elements.

Answer (score -1):

Let's teach you some better coding practices:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, Q, S, old = onload; // for use on other pages - read note below
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Q = function(selector){
  return doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
S = function(selector){
  return doc.querySelector(selector);
}
var firstLast = I('first_last'), opt = I('opt'), out = I('output'), o1 = out.firstChild, o2 = o1.nextSibling;
I('form').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
opt.onclick = function(){
  if(firstLast.value){
    o1.innerHTML = o2.innerHTML = 'My name is '+firstLast.value;
   }
}
firstLast.onfocus = function(){
  o1.innerHTML = o2.innerHTML = '';
}
} // end onload
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#aaa; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form' name='form'>
      <input id='first_last' name='first_last' type='text' />
      <input id='opt' name='opt' type='button' value='Make My Signature' />
    </form>
    <div id='output'><div></div><div></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Separate your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, so it can be cached.